# Are the gstreamer packages completely open source?

Tags: fedora, ffmpeg, free-software, gstreamer, open-source

I'm on Fedora 26 and I'd like to be able to play certain video formats which I can only play by installing packages from a non-free repository.

However, I do not want to install any packages that are not fully open source (e.g. contain proprietary binary blobs).

On the [rpmfusion FAQ page](https://rpmfusion.org/FAQ#What_packages_should_I_install_to_be_able_to_play_nonfree_codecs.3F) it is suggested to install: `gstreamer-plugins-ugly` and `gstreamer-plugins-bad` and `gstreamer-ffmpeg`.

I know that ffmpeg is not completely open source because of [its NVENC library](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/LICENSE.md#incompatible-libraries) and maybe even more.

So, my question is: Do the above mentioned packages contain any kind of proprietary binary blobs or other closed source components or are they completely open source?

Comment: ffmpeg is completely open-source. Certain optional libraries are under different licenses and may not be open source. Since you wish to *play* videos, NVENC is not necessary.

Comment: NVENC may not be neccessary, but is it in the gstreamer-ffmpeg package anyways?